# What is the difference between `tensorflow.nn.np` and `numpy`?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Does `tensorflow.nn.np` simply call `numpy` or it is implemented in `tensorflow`'s c++ back-end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, print out the module.

```
import tensorflow
print(tensorflow.nn.np)
```

For me it prints:

```
<module 'numpy' from '/Users/ch/miniconda/envs/sb35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py'>
```

So `tensorflow.nn.np` is just an alias for numpy.